# Chrome automatically adding bookmarks to bookmarks bar

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is automatically adding some websites as bookmarks to my bookmarks bar. I am not accidentally adding them through CTRL + D or otherwise. What could be causing this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: When you hit the icon to save the bookmark, what folder are you saving the bookmark to?

Comment: Does it happen in Incognito mode ?

Comment: There may be an add-on doing this, installed by you, or when a third-party app containing adware was installed. Use BrowserAddonsView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_addons_view.html, to check for all add-ons.